# How to resume an application from another application?

Tags: android, resume

Actually, I know how to launch an application from another application.

The problem is that the application always restarts instead of resuming when I launch it from another application after launching it from home screen. (I mean the application is running first by pressing the shortcut from home screen)

For example,
There are two applications : A, B

1. Launch two applications from home screen first.
2. Launch A application again from B application.
3. A application restarts instead of resuming.

How could I resume it?
Now I am doing it as below.

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PACKAGE);
intent.setAction(ACTION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

ACTION is custom action.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) flag on your Intent when you call [Context.startActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER category and Intent.ACTION_MAIN action in the intent that starts the initial Activity. 
If those two flags are present and the Activity is not at the root of the task (ie..  app was already running), then I call finish() on the initial Activity. That exact solution may not work for you, but something similar should.

Here is what I do in `onCreate()` of the initial/launch Activity:

```
if (!isTaskRoot()
        && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        && getIntent().getAction() != null
        && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

    finish();
    return;
}
```